# What is a simple way to increase distanced to the far clipping plane in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5, perspective, graphical-programming

I'm trying to set the far clipping plane to a higher value, but I'm a bit lost.

I'm looking at a complex object using a [QMatrix4x4](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmatrix4x4.html#lookAt) camera persepective like that:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
m_view = QMatrix4x4();
m_view.lookAt(QVector3D(17.f, 36.f, 36.f),  // eye
              QVector3D(17.f,  0.f, 19.f),  // center
              QVector3D( 0.f,  0.f, -1.f)); // up
glLoadMatrixf(m_view.data());
```

Now, looking from this perspective, my object is being clipped by the far plane.

[image: far plane clip]

I've tried to increase the far plane distance by using a [frustum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmatrix4x4.html#frustum) matrix operation with a huge value. All I want is to modify the back clipping plane:

```
m_view.frustum(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 200000.f);
```

But this does not show any difference, modifying the `farPlane` parameter does not change anything. The same applies to [ortho](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmatrix4x4.html#ortho):

```
m_view.ortho(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 200000.f);
```

Or [perspective](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmatrix4x4.html#perspective):

```
m_view.perspective(0.f, 1.f, 1.f, 200000.f);
```

What's wrong with my approach? How to modify the far clipping plane?

---

#### Edit

I've extended the code snippets above as the problem was not visible. Obviously my mistake was modifying the `GL_MODELVIEW` instead of the `GL_PROJECTION`.

Working code should look like that:

```
// Projection
m_projection = QMatrix4x4();
m_projection.perspective(20.f, m_width / m_height, 0.01f, 2000.f); // note the far plane
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(m_projection.data());
// Model view
m_view = QMatrix4x4();
m_view.lookAt(QVector3D(17.f, 36.f, 36.f),  // eye
              QVector3D(17.f,  0.f, 19.f),  // center
              QVector3D( 0.f,  0.f, -1.f)); // up
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(m_view.data());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues:

1. You are mixing modelview (lookat) and projection (frustum) operations on the same matrix. You need 2 different matrices.
2. You define the left and right values as both 1.f in ::frustum(). It cannot work, they need to be different.
   Same for the top and bottom values.

Here is an extract of the definition of QMatrix4x4::frustum():

```
if (left == right || bottom == top || nearPlane == farPlane)    
    return *this;
```

So your call to frustum does not do anything.

Once you have good values for top/left/top/bottom, try playing with the near plane distance too, as it might be it that clips your object and not the far plane.

Comment: No effect with both zero and negative values. :(

Comment: up using a negative value for the z axis might be a problem, try using a negative value for the far clipping plane too. Also, make sure this is what you want. up usually is (0,1,0) (y axis points up).

Comment: Yeah, did that, too. Modifying near and far in any direction does not show any effect.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure m_view is used afterwards? If you change it and it has no effect, maybe it's because it's not in effect at all and you're changing a variable which is otherwise unused.

Comment: Yes. See at the code in my question, `m_view.lookAt()` works as desired, but `m_view.frustum()` is not doing anything with the near and far planes at all. Modifying the left,right,top,bottom parameters of frustum is indeed working somehow. Just the near and far planes are not.

Comment: I just realized: your left and right values are the same. And top and bottom too. All 1.f. It cannot work. Editing answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32637/discussion-between-donschoe-and-yohan-danvin)